# primefaces 5.0 datatable filter create new selection object

Tags: primefaces, filter, datatable

Our project is working with Primefaces v5.0 ( Because of some system requirement, we have to downgrade to this version ).

Before, when we use higher version, datatable filter work fine. The selection value was keep as user filter the datatable.

But now back on v5.0, when user filter and the selected row disappear from table, primeface set selection to null. And when we clear the filter, selected row appear again but sometime it not highlight. Whenever that happen, we check the backing bean selection value and it appear to be another object not in the datatable list object ( event though it has the same value but different address ).

Since we know higher version doesnt have this behavior. But as mention before, we can't change to another version. So anyone can tell me the reason and how to fix this in version 5.0? Thank you!

Comment: add some code to see if there's any problem on your code

Comment: It work normal on 5.3, only when downgrade to 5.0, this happen. I check postData value on PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.send, selection value which send to server is correct but the object put into setter is incorrect. And it happen on all table in our project. So i doubt it come from somewhere else like how Primeface work, instead of our code